# H2 driver not found when try to connect

Tags: classpath, h2, netbeans-7

I have gone through some other answers, but cannot get the solution to my problem.

I am using NetBeans 7.0.1 and the latest version of the H2 DB on Win7.

I successfully use the H2 console tool and I have also added the driver in NetBeans and am able to connect (i.e. see the DB, tables, issue commands, etc). However from within my Java code when running it, I get the message: "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:org.h2.Driver".
My code is:

```
Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/testDB", "sa", "");
Statement query = null;
query = conn.createStatement();
String firstString = "INSERT INTO ......";
query.executeUpdate(firstString);
```

I have also added the H2 jar file in the classpath (although I had to create the classpath myself and point to the jar file) - I went to environment variables -> user variables

```
name=classpath value=.;C:\NetBeansProjects\testdemo\src\testdemo\DB\h2-1.3.165.jar
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If the error message is `ClassNotFoundException: org.h2.Driver` then the H2 driver is not in the classpath. I don't know how to configure the classpath in Netbeans however.

Comment: I just had to add the H2 jar file in the "Libraries" section under the source code packages.

Comment: OK, I have added the answer for you (of course you can also do that yourself).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the H2 jar file in the "Libraries" section under the source code packages.

Comment: had to manually add the jar to my project as I could not get it to work with maven

Answer (score 0):

Change parent version

spring-boot-starter-parent
        1.4.3.RELEASE