# How to embedded and make protable database for a java standalone apploication?

Tags: java, database, jar, portability

I am working in a java stand alone application which connect with a database(later i'll explain which database).

Now after generate the jar file,its working fine in my system where i create the application.

but when i want to run that jar file in another system,its running correctly but in the login part (where the database terms coming),when i click on a button which will open the login window it passes an exception,-- "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException.org.h2.Driver"(i'm using h2 database).

But there's no such problem in that system where i create that application.

Firstly i used MySQL database..but i search in the internet that MySQL is not portable database. so i switch to H2 database which is an embedded database.
i did same whatever they said to embedded h2 database.  But still i got the same problem..
My database is still not portable.

I want that whenever i generate the jar file,the database which has all the data of my application is bound with the jar file.and same for creating .exe file...that is when i take the .jar or .exe file to another system and want to run it there,the database should go along with my jar or exe file.

i have seen this websites,but unable to get the solutions..
[Finished Java project, now creating jar or .exe file (with Database)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18580731/finished-java-project-now-creating-jar-or-exe-file-with-database)

[How to Bind MySql Database inside a JAR file of any application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6872183/how-to-bind-mysql-database-inside-a-jar-file-of-any-application)

please help.i need your help badly.

Comment: Have you tried the solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9987525/h2-driver-not-found-when-try-to-connect

Comment: yeah.i tried that also.my h2.jar file class path is set correctly..its running in my system but not in other system.

Answer (score 0):

[Java DB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javadb/overview/index.html) or Derby could be good choice. It is already embedded into Java and so it always exist. It is also pretty simple and powerful.